# Finding dotted contours in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to extract the separate contours in this image.
[image: Input Image v2]
This is what I've tried and i'm getting the result below (see green lines). Does anyone know how i might improve the contour detection and ideally stop detecting the numbers?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Image
img = cv2.imread('contours_input.PNG', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# Create a grayscale image and denoise it
im_gs = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gsdn = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(im_gs, h=3)
# Create an inverted B&W copy using Otsu (automatic) thresholding
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gsdn, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# Find Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Convert back to RGB
im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(im_bw, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
# Draw Contours
cv2.drawContours(im_bw, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
# Write Image
cv2.imwrite('countours_output.png',im_bw)
```

[image: Output Image v2]

Comment: full res input please, if you want people to experiment with your data -- line segments are narrow, numbers are not. that's how you could filter out some digits (except the `1` digits). -- line segments also tend to follow each other and have similar curvature. random `1` digit strokes aren't part of a contour line

Comment: I've uploaded slightly higher resolution images, unfortunately the original images are quite low res.

Comment: this is a tricky situation. I don't see a simple and sure solution.

Comment: You could try to close the gaps and remove the few "dots" in the input image through a combination of morphological operations. Preventing the numbers from being detected is not straightforward; You could employ some form of OCR to get a bounding box around the numbers and then set the region to white, if you are willing to go that extent.